# Using Spherical Bessel Functions in Python

Tags: python, special-functions

My question relates to using *spherical Bessel functions* in Python.

If my ODE contains a spherical Bessel function of the form $$j_\ell(tx)$$ and similarly $$y_\ell(tx)$$

for given values of $t$ and $x$.

I used the following:

```
from scipy.special import spherical_jn(n, z, derivative)
from scipy.special import spherical_yn(n, z, derivative)
```

I thought I could maybe define jn as follows:

```
def Jn(tx,n):
    return (sqrt(pi/(2*(t*x))*jn(n+0.5,t*x))
```

And then just input it into my ODE.

Any help here is appreciated. I can post the ODE if required.

Comment: I think  it depends on how you want to solve the ODE... with your own method, i.e. coding by yourself, or if you want to use an ODE solver available in python as odeint?

Comment: I would like to code it myself. Should I post the ODE for you to view perhaps?

Comment: Well, if you have to code it by yourself, it should be fine if you write it by yourself. Also, check that your implementation's results agrees with python's ones.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "I thought I could maybe define jn as follows...and then just input it into my own ODE" Are you asking a hypothetical question? Or have you tried and gotten something unexpected?